# Find the eigenvalues and find a basis for each eigenspace.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvalues and find a basis for each eigenspace.

$$\begin{equation*}
A_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 && -0.6 \\
0.75 && 1.1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

So the characteristic polynomial is det(A - $\lambda$I) =

$$$$\begin{equation*}
A_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 - \lambda && -0.6 \\
0.75 && 1.1 - \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$$$

$$= 0.55 - 0.5 \lambda - 1.1 \lambda + \lambda^2 + 0.45 = \lambda^2 - 1.6 \lambda + 1$$

I'm a bit stuck here. Any help?

Eventually I get the roots are $\lambda_1 =  \frac{4}{5} + i\frac{3}{5}$ and $\lambda_2 = \frac{4}{5} - i \frac{3}{5}$

So how do I go from here?

Comment: By solving that quadratic equation $\det = 0$, the two roots seem to be complex.

Comment: Is this a problem??? Did I do something wrong?? @peterwhy

Comment: I don't see mistake in your expansion, so I guess the question is really looking for complex eigenvalues. Go on and solve the quadratic equation, then for each root $\lambda$ find a (complex) vector $\mathbf v$ that satisfies $$(A-\lambda I)\mathbf v = 0.$$

Comment: Mind showing me how @peterwhy? I don't think I've done a problem like this before. I added more to the problem and I think I have the eigenvalues.

Comment: Some... And you'll never learn if you keep asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: @SomeHoppin You have changed the question enough that existing answers become irrelevant. Also, there can't be eigenvalues and eigenvectors for that non-square matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the quadratic equation, for example $\lambda_2 = 0.8 - 0.6i$ is a root:

$$\begin{align*}
\det[A-(0.8-0.6i)]
&= (0.8-0.6i)^2 -1.6 (0.8-0.6i) + 1\\
&= 0.64 - 0.96i - 0.36 - 1.28 + 0.96i + 1\\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

Then solving the equation $(A-\lambda_2 I)\mathbf v = 0$,

$$\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{0.5-\lambda_2 & -0.6\\0.75 & 1.1-\lambda_2} \mathbf v &= 0\\
\pmatrix{-0.3+0.6i & -0.6\\0.75 & 0.3+0.6i} \mathbf v &= 0\\
\pmatrix{-0.3+0.6i & -0.6\\0.75(0.3-0.6i) & (0.3+0.6i)(0.3-0.6i)} \mathbf v &= 0 && R_2 \to (0.3-0.6i)R_2\\
\pmatrix{-0.3+0.6i & -0.6\\0.75(0.3-0.6i) & 0.09 + 0.36} \mathbf v &= 0\\
\pmatrix{-0.3+0.6i & -0.6\\0.75(0.3-0.6i) & 0.45} \mathbf v &= 0\\
\pmatrix{-0.3+0.6i & -0.6\\0 & 0} \mathbf v &= 0 && R_2 \to R_2 + 0.75R_1\\
\mathbf v &= k\pmatrix{0.6\\-0.3+0.6i}
\end{align*}$$

Similar for the remaining complex eigenvalues.